# ERROR: COPY delimiter must be a single one-byte character

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-copy

I want to load the data from a flat file with delimiter "~,~" into a PostgreSQL table. I have tried it as below but looks like there is a restriction for the delimiter. If COPY statement doesn't allow multiple chars for delimiter, is there any alternative to do this?

```
metadb=# \COPY public.CME_DATA_STAGE_TRANS FROM 'E:\Infor\Outbound_Marketing\7.2.1\EM\metadata\pgtrans.log' WITH      DELIMITER AS '~,~'
ERROR:  COPY delimiter must be a single one-byte character
\copy: ERROR:  COPY delimiter must be a single one-byte character
```

Answer (score 16):

If you are using [Vertica](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/BulkLoadCOPY/LoadingUTF-8FormatData.htm), you could use E'\t'or U&'\0009'

> To indicate a non-printing delimiter character (such as a tab),
>   specify the character in extended string syntax (E'...'). If your
>   database has StandardConformingStrings enabled, use a Unicode string
>   literal (U&'...'). For example, use either E'\t' or U&'\0009' to
>   specify tab as the delimiter.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunatelly there is no way to load flat file with multiple characters delimiter `~,~` in Postgres unless you want to modify [source code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/commands/copy.c) (and recompile of course) by yourself in some (terrific) way:

```c
/* Only single-byte delimiter strings are supported. */
if (strlen(cstate->delim) != 1)
    ereport(ERROR,
        (errcode(ERRCODE_FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED),
    errmsg("COPY delimiter must be a single one-byte character")));
```

What you want is to **preprocess** your input file with some external tool, for example `sed` might to be best companion on GNU/Linux platfom, for example:

```
sed s/~,~/\\t/g inputFile
```

Comment: is ther any way i can denote(either ASCII repr. or anytother) escape or vertical tab characters as a singly byte character and use any of them as a delimiter?

Comment: I am not sure I am undestand your question. You could write e.g. `DELIMITER E'\x3A'` for `:` ASCII hex representation as well `E'\xB'` for vertical tab (VT) character.

Answer (score 4):

The obvious thing to do is what all other answers advised. Edit import file. I would do that, too.

However, as a proof of concept, here are two ways to accomplish this *without additional tools*.

### 1) General solution

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_import_file(OUT my_count integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    myfile    text;  -- read xml file into that var.
    datafile text := '\path\to\file.txt'; -- !pg_read_file only accepts relative path in database dir!
BEGIN

myfile := pg_read_file(datafile, 0, 100000000);  -- arbitrary 100 MB max.

INSERT INTO public.my_tbl
SELECT ('(' || regexp_split_to_table(replace(myfile, '~,~', ','), E'\n') || ')')::public.my_tbl;

-- !depending on file format, you might need additional quotes to create a valid format.

GET DIAGNOSTICS my_count = ROW_COUNT;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

*This uses a number of pretty advanced features. If anybody is actually interested and needs an explanation, leave a comment to this post and I will elaborate.*

### 2) Special case

**If** you can guarantee that '~' is only present in the delimiter '~,~', then you can go ahead with a plain COPY in this special case. Just treat ',' in '~,~' as an additional columns.
Say, your table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (a int, b int, c int);
```

Then you can (in one transaction):

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo_tmp ON COMMIT DROP (
 a int, tmp1 "char"
,b int, tmp2 "char"
,c int);

COPY foo_tmp FROM '\path\to\file.txt' WITH DELIMITER AS '~';

ALTER TABLE foo_tmp DROP COLUMN tmp1;
ALTER TABLE foo_tmp DROP COLUMN tmp2;

INSERT INTO foo SELECT * FROM foo_tmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if you're looking for a postgresql solution or just a general one.

If it were me, I would open up a copy of vim (or gvim) and run the commend `:%s/~,~/~/g`
That replaces all "~,~" with "~".

Comment: hmm..i am looking for a postgresql solution.

Comment: If you google around, you'll find this is a known limitation without a good workaround.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a single character delimiter, open `notepad` press `ctrl+h` replace `~,~` with something will not interfere. like `|`

Comment: no my application keeps the data in a flat file with `~,~` delimeter and we can't change that behaviour. one our data extraction job load this file into  postgresql table. So, please stop suggestging the replacement solutions. If copy statement in PostgreSQL doesn't allow multple chars for delimiter is there any way to load the data just like oracle's SQLLoader.

Comment: Why can't you copy the file.. than replace.. then load using COPY