# PostgreSQL can't catch exception in loop

Tags: postgresql, exception

I have some data stored in txt file in the format like this:

```
aaaa----bbbb
cccc----dddd
...
```

However, the file may contains some redundant data in invalid format like this:

```
eeee----ffff----
hhhh
...
```

And now I want to import the data to a PostgreSQL table which has two text columns, and ignore the invalid lines at the same time. So I write a function below imitating [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930242/error-copy-delimiter-must-be-a-single-one-byte-character).

```
 1  create or replace function import_data(in filepath text, out my_count integer) returns integer as
 2  $BODY$
 3  declare
 4          content text;
 5          oid integer;
 6          it text;
 7  begin
 8          oid := lo_import(filepath);
 9          content := encode(lo_get(oid, 0, 300000000), 'escape');
10  
11          content := replace(content, ',', '\,');
12          content := replace(content, '----', ',');
13          content := trim(content, E'\n');
14  
15          --begin
16          --      insert into public.mytable select (E'(\'' || regexp_split_to_table(content, E'\n') || E'\')')::public.mytable;
17          --exception when others then
18          --end;
19  
20          for it in select('(' || regexp_split_to_table(content, E'\n') || ')')::public.mytable loop
21                  begin
22                          insert into public.mytable select (it);
23                  exception when others then
24                          raise notice 'error occurred when importing file: %s', filepath;
25                  end;
26          end loop;
27  
28          perform lo_unlink(oid);
29  
30          get diagnostics my_count = ROW_COUNT;
31  end;
32  $BODY$
33          LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

if I use the code commented from line 15 to line 18, it seems that PostgreSQL can catch the `too_many_columns` exception correctly. However, if I use the code from line 20 to line 26, PostgreSQL cannot catch the exception when `too_many_columns` occurs:

```
=> select import_data('/run/media/test.rec');
ERROR:  malformed record literal: "(eeee,ffff,)"
DETAIL:  Too many columns.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function import_data(text) line 20 at FOR over SELECT rows
```

The reason why I use the code from line 20 to line 26 is that I want to keep the records inserted before remained in the database but not rolled back as explained [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING):

> When an error is caught by an EXCEPTION clause, the local variables of the PL/pgSQL function remain as they were when the error occurred, but all changes to persistent database state within the block are rolled back.

The first question is how can I ignore the exceptions correctly?

And the second question is why there is a `too_many_columns` error in PostgreSQL but there isn't a `too_few_columns` error?

Comment: Perhaps you can, instead, use `COPY table_name FROM PROGRAM 'command'`, where `command` is a program or script (perl, python, or whatever you're skill in and that is suitable for easily processing and formatting a text file, and outputting CSV or TSV to STDOUT).

Comment: That's because the exception occurs in line 20 (in `select` statement, while converting result of `regexp_split_to_table` to `mytable` datatype), but you catch exceptions in line 22. One of possible solutions is to write a set-returning function to filter out malformed lines.

Comment: @EgorRogov Oh! I see! I have ever thought the `CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function import_data(text) line 20 at FOR over SELECT rows` meant that the error occurs in FOR loop. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister That's awesome! It is what I want! Thanks!